# Backing up redshift database

Tags: amazon-redshift, database-backups

I want to backup entire redshift cluster, such that I can use it in other databases like mysql or hadoop in future.
I was looking up and creating a manual screenshot seems to be an option but I guess that wont work for cross database languages.
So what would be the detailed steps to backup the entire cluster of redshift

Answer (score 0):

Cluster backups can be done via the aws console, however these can only be restored to another redshift cluster.

Because Redshift is not the same as postgres in many ways, it will be inpossible / tricky to use standard tools like pg_dump and pg_restore.

I think that your best option is to :

1. extract the ddl from the Redshift tables that you wish to create elsewhere, most ide's have a simple way to do this.
2. modify the ddl to work with your target database (e.g. postgres will
   be easy, mysql harder)
3. copy the contents of the Redshift database, one table at a time to s3 using
   the unload command
4. import the data that you unloaded in step 3 to your target tables